# PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get this error 
23/112    PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator 
It's pointing to AND CURRENT OF statement..

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE alga_uz_pasirodyma(grupe_id in grupes.id%TYPE, alga in out number)
IS 
v_kliento_id nariai.asm_kodas%TYPE;
TYPE bendras IS RECORD (
alga number
);
globalus bendras;
 CURSOR c_klientai IS
 SELECT nariai.asm_kodas
 FROM nariai
 where nariai.fk_grupe = grupe_id
 FOR UPDATE OF nariai.alga;

BEGIN  
  globalus.alga:= alga; 
  IF grupe_id <= 0 THEN
         raise_application_error(-20101, 'Nepavyko surasti grupes');
  END IF;
 OPEN c_klientai;
 LOOP
 FETCH c_klientai INTO v_kliento_id;
 EXIT WHEN c_klientai%NOTFOUND;
 UPDATE nariai set nariai.alga = nariai.alga * globalus.alga where nariai.asm_kodas = v_kliento_id AND CURRENT OF c_klientai;
 END LOOP;
 UPDATE grupes set grupes.pasirodymu_kiekis = grupes.pasirodymu_kiekis + 1  where grupes.id = grupe_id;
SELECT max(nariai.alga) into alga from nariai where nariai.fk_grupe = grupe_id;
 CLOSE c_klientai;
END alga_uz_pasirodyma;
```

What should I do? I believe everything is declared correctly in the where statement..

Answer (score 0):

"CURRENT OF" should be by itself in the where clause.   It allows you to update or delete the record at the current loop iteration of the cursor.

On a different note, I don't see you doing anything significant in the loop to warrant a cursor.    Ignore this note if that will change, otherwise just run the update "where nariai.fk_grupe = grupe_id"

Comment: Thanks for the input, but what exactly should I change in my code to avoid the error? :D

Comment: UPDATE nariai set nariai.alga = nariai.alga * globalus.alga where CURRENT OF c_klientai;